# GWT Watermarked (AKA placeholder) ListBox

Tags: user-interface, gwt, dom

I want to have in my gwt application a ListBox with a watermark.
I already created TextBox and a DateBox with a watermark by extending those classes and the property placeholder of the DOM.
However I could not such property for the ListBox. There isn't any, right? (how can I tell? except for trying.)
Assuming that there is no such property I would like to implement such a class by extending ListBox.
I am not sure how such a ListBox would behave.
could you please help me define the behaviour of such ListBox or maybe you know a site that uses one so I could play with it? Or just point me to a code example.

Thanks

Comment: You're right, there's no `placeholder` attribute on list boxes (`select` elements): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-select-element.html#the-select-element while there is on `input` elements (used by TextBox and DateBox widgets) http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary

Comment: Actually the link that you provided does describe the select element placeholder...
I suspect it is somehow possible to use the select element's placeholder in gwt ListBox...
That would make a much nicer implementation for a ListBox with a watermark/placeholder cause we won't have to override any ListBox functions...

Comment: What it does describe is that a list item with an empty-string value that is also the very first option of the list is called a _placeholder_ if the `select` has a `required` attribute. It's still an option in the list though, it just happens to be selected by default (and to cause the list to be _invalid_ when using _form validation_, which not many browsers do support). Not quite the same as a `placeholder` on an `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it would be a non editable list item as the placeholder.  You could have the setPlaceholder set the text on the list item.  The placeholder list item would only be visible when the list was empty.  You couldn't select the list item, and all methods to access list items would never see it.

Comment: So basically what you are saying (I think) is having another item in the list which will act a watermark/placeholder and overriding all the relevant ListBox's public interface to act as though this item does not exist...?  
Is it technically possible to set the placeholder property for just that item?

Comment: It is possible.  I am probably going to need such a list soon.  I use placeholder text in most of my UI as small instructions - such as 'Enter your xyz'.  I have created placeholder versions of a few of the widgets.  I have also been debating (with myself) the list version.